# Symfony2 + Doctrine + MySQL Designing database revision history

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to create a custom CMS where pages can be created and a user can update the page title, content, meta header, meta keywords and meta description. Each page can have multiple documents and images but I also want to record the revision history of each page. Also, each page can have one parent and multiple children. However, I'm unsure of the best approach and whether related entities such as images, documents etc should be linked to the page table or the revision table?!

I was thinking:

```
**page table**

id 
parent_id
position

**revision table**

id page_id 
title 
content 
meta_header 
meta_description 
meta_keywords 
date_created 
date_modified

**page_images table**

id 
page_id or page_revision_id ?? 
image_id 
date_created 
date_modified

**images table**

id image_name 
image_path

**page_documents table**

page_id or page_revision_id ?? 
document_id 
date_created 
date_modified

**documents table**

id 
document_name 
document_path
```

However, Im not sure if images and documents should be related to the page table or the page_revision table? Also, things such as the position of a page and the parent_id which won't be amended by the page version, should this be in the page or page_version table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `Loggable Doctrine Behaviour`?

http://gediminasm.org/article/loggable-behavioral-extension-for-doctrine2

Comment: No, didn't know about that to be honest, I'll have a look.